# Why does Template Haskell add unexpected parens?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I have the following:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Language.Haskell.TH


mkExp :: [Name] -> ExpQ
mkExp (name:[]) = [| ZipList $(varE name) |]
mkExp (name:names) = [| ZipList $(varE name) <*> $(mkExp names) |]

zipN :: Int -> ExpQ
zipN n = do
  names <- mapM newName $ replicate n "x"
  fn <- newName "f"
  let vps = map varP (fn:names)
  lamE vps $ [| $(varE fn) <$> $(mkExp names) |]
```

I'd like `$(zipN 2)` to generate:

```
\f x y -> f <$> ZipList x <*> ZipList y
```

so that it has the type `(a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]`. But poking around the output from `-ddump-splices` and filtering out the noise, I've found that `$(zipN 2)` instead generates:

```
\f x y -> f <$> ((ZipList x) <*> (ZipList y))
```

with the type `(a -> b) -> [a1 -> a] -> [a1] -> ZipList b`. Similarly, `$(zipN 3)` generates:

```
\f x1 x2 x3 -> (f <$> ((ZipList x1) <*> ((ZipList x2) <*> (ZipList x3)))
```

so it looks like each instance of `$([|...|])` is being replaced with `(...)` rather than `...`, which is surprising to me, since the docs seemed to say that pairs of `$( )` and `[| |]` "cancelled out."

Why does Template Haskell generate this AST, and what can I do to get a function from it with the correct type?

Comment: The `...` [must be an expression](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.2/docs/html/users_guide/template-haskell.html). Template haskell operates at the level of expressions, not tokens. The expression `e = x <*> y` means the same thing as `e = (<*>) x y`. Substituting `e` into `f <$> e` or `(<$>) f e` results in `f <$> (x <*> y)` or `(<$>) f ((<*>) x y)`. This is different than `f <$> x <*> y` or `(f <$> x) <*> y` or `((<*>) (<$>) f x) y)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `<$>` and `<*>` are left associative. You are right associating them.

You can build the expression so that the operators are left-associated instead.

```
mkExp' :: ExpQ -> [Name] -> ExpQ
mkExp' acc [] = acc
mkExp' acc (name:names) = mkExp'' [| $(acc) <$> ZipList $(varE name) |] names
    where
        mkExp'' acc [] = acc
        mkExp'' acc (name:names) = mkExp'' [| $(acc) <*> ZipList $(varE name) |] names

zipN :: Int -> ExpQ
zipN n = do
  names <- mapM newName $ replicate n "x"
  fn <- newName "f"
  let vps = map varP (fn:names)
  lamE vps $ mkExp' (varE fn) names
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess it didn't occur to me that building the AST in a certain way implicitly forced a certain associativity on the operations. Another quick question, if you have the time --- why does adding `getZipList $` before `$(acc)` cause a type error? In (what I assume to be) the equivalent code `\f x y -> getZipList $ f <$> ZipList x <*> ZipList y`, the types work out fine --- what's changed here?

Comment: @PatrickCollins You're probably making `(getZipList (f <$> ZipList x)) <*> ZipList y`. Try `[| getZipList $(mkExp' (varE fn) names) |]`. You want to `getZipList` the overall result, not some sub-expression nested deep in the left side of things.